# Hive failed to show tables in warehouse

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive

the problem I’m facing is that when I create a table inside hive the table only shows up in
localhost:50070/explorer.html#/user/hive/warehouse
,but it does not exist the real directory inside the terminal or hard disk on the directory
/user/hive/warehouse

Answer (score 0):

Reason you might not have used Location when creation your create table command. You should use it like:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
....
....
LOCATION 'hdfs://user/hive/warehouse'
```

Comment: Why are you redirecting using ">". Location is part of create command. See syntax [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTable)

Comment: so hdfs:... should be http://localhost:50075/user/hive/warehouse, so something like create table pro(word string) LOCATION 'hdfs://localhost:50075/user/hive/warehouse'

Comment: You have wrong port of hdfs as above i think its for job tracker. Please check core-site.xml for your hdfs port what you defined. Probably it should be 8020